# Overlapping error bars and error bar color in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am new to R and have been using ggplot2 to create a line graph where I basically monitor the growth of bacteria over time. I'm having problem with the error bars for the points on my graph. I have two issues: 1) The color of my error bars are black and I instead would like them to be the same color as the points they eminate from, and 2) the error bars are overlapping making it difficult to see what is going on. My data can be found here https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0qf6iji2is95v0/bna6cumulativefinalCSV.csv. The code I have used to this point is below. Also the scales package must be installed in order for the y-axis to be appropriate.

```
ggplot(data, aes(Time,Survival, group = Strains)) + 
geom_line(aes(colour = Strains)) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Survival - SD, ymax = Survival + SD), width=5) + 
geom_point(aes(colour=Strains),size=3) + 
theme_bw() + theme(legend.title=element_blank()) + 
theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "italic"))+ 
xlab("Time (hours)") + ylab("Survival") + labs(title = "Survival in Starvation media") + scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x),labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x))) + 
theme(legend.key = element_blank()) + 
theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = "grey"))
```

This is the resulting image
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3vb8acgq7n9bk8/dropbox.pdf

thank you

Comment: Notice how you put `aes(colour = Strains)` in other layers, but not the errorbar one? There's a connection there with your first problem. But more generally, remember that aesthetics mapped at the "top level" in `ggplot()` cascade down to all layers, saving you the trouble of retyping them.

Comment: Thanks so much Joran I didnt know about the cascading of the aesthetics. I added the colour=strains the first line of code and that fixed the first issue. Do you have any idea how to prevent the error bars from overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color can be fixed by changing your first line to `ggplot(data, aes(Time,Survival, group = Strains, coulour = Strains)) +`, and then removing the other calls to `colour`.

To separate the error bars, you might try to jitter the points and error bars together.  See this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/l_DZZXi5B0s